# react native Marker inside MapView is not showing

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying to get map view to work, when I am using the code below I can see the map at the right location but no sign to my Marker, I tried removing dark mode and giving the Marker an Image but still no result.

Maybe you can locate the problem and help me.
Thank you very much.
 
Using react-native with expo, testing on my IOS device.

```
<MapView
  style={{ flex: 1 }}
  initialRegion={{
    latitude: 32.060797,
    longitude: 34.7617,
    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
  }}
>
  <Marker
    pinColor={"#d62424"}
    coordinate={{
      latitude: 32.060797,
      longitude: 34.7617
    }}

    image={require('../assets/images/icon.png')}
  />
</MapView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, instead of using `Marker` just use `MapView.Marker`.
I hope I fixed your problem as well!